# How to project the geographic grid in a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to automatically project the geographic grid (View -> Decorations -> Grid) into a shapefile layer in QGIS?

Comment: I think you mean vectorize a grid into a shapefile?  Is that what you're trying to do, take a raster and form it into a vector layer?  I am assuming you mean a Grid file.  If you mean the data frame, then ignore my comment.

Comment: No, what I mean is to vectorize the QGIS grid that appears as an option with view -> Decorations -> Grid.

Comment: I was trying to just "copy" (vectorized a grid). But it is almost as simple to do Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector grid and then enter grid extent etc.